Rings where addition and multiplication are same
I'm an undergrad currently taking Abstract Algebra. When learning the definition of a ring, I came up with the following (hopefully interesting) question:
List all rings up to isomorphism such that the addition and multiplication operations are identical. That is $a+b = ab$ for all $a,b \in R$.
My thought was to use the distributive property and say that if $(a+b)c = ac+bc$ for all $a,b,c \in R$ and $*=+$, then $a+b+c = a+c+b+c$. Then, using the fact that $+$ must be commutative and cancellation, we get $c=0$, but this must be true for all $c \in R$, so $R$ can only have one element and thus the only possible $R$ is the trivial ring.
Not sure if this proof is correct, but I was wondering if anyone had any more intuitive approaches to why this might be the only group where this is possible.

That sounds right! A more straightforward proof might be that for any $c \in R$, we have $c = c+0 = c*0 = 0$. Keeping $a$ and $b$ arbitrary in a proof like that is actually slightly bad form. If you've got a statement that works for any values, it can be helpful to just pick the simplest ones and see where that leads you.

Please don't answer duplicate questions. Your proof already appears in the linked duplicate. For some background see here.

There is a simpler proof. $(R,+,*)$ is a ring then if * equals + then also $(R,*)$ is an abelian group, then it must exist the inverse of $0$ in $(R,*)$ and this is true if and only if $(R,+,*)$ is trivial.

I admit that the proof is simple. However, how can anything be simpler than $c=c+0=c\cdot 0=0$, from the other proof. Your proof is using an abelian group, which is much harder than to say that $0\cdot c=0$.

Well these are equivalent proofs :). I thought as "simpler" because it is does not invoke arithmetical manipulation but the fact that 0 cannot have an inverse (unless we have a trivial ring). But they are equivalent proofs indeed.

Please don't answer duplicate questions. For some background see here.
